# repeat incrementing list partial number of times

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to assign months based on the week number. I tried:

```
full = data.frame(group = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'), week = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2))
full %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(month = rep(1, 4, each = length(group) / 4))
```

for the output to be:

```
   group week month
1      a    1     1
2      a    2     1
3      a    3     1
4      a    4     1
5      a    5     2
6      b    1     1
7      b    2     1
8      b    3     1
9      c    1     1
10     c    2     1
```

however, the above code returns the error

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     Column `month` must be length 5 (the group size) or one, not 4

Is there anyway to repeat something a partial lengths like of times:`rep(1:2, each = 1.5`) to be `1, 1, 2`, instead of `1, 2`?

Answer (score 1):

You can treat weeks as Dates and use `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
full %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(month = lubridate::month(origin + lubridate::weeks(x=week)))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   group [3]
    group  week month
   <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1      a     1     1
 2      a     2     1
 3      a     3     1
 4      a     4     1
 5      a     5     2
 6      b     1     1
 7      b     2     1
 8      b     3     1
 9      c     1     1
10      c     2     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `floor` instead:

```
full %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(month = floor((1:length(group) + 3)/4))
```